# My list view isn't populating, is there something wrong with my Adapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm currently trying to pull from one table but display different results from different sql queries into different listviews on the same activity.
currently it's not populating the listview.

it was populating when I only had the one listview however it's not what I wanted as it only displayed one sql query

adapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="#FEE851"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.016"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.14" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvlearningstyle"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#FEE851"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.055"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.14" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Adapterlist

```
package com.example.jcw3;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdapterList extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> n,p;
    GroupList l;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public AdapterList(GroupList data,ArrayList<String> name,ArrayList<String> learningstyle){
        this.l=data;
        this.n=name;
        this.p=learningstyle;
        this.inflater=LayoutInflater.from(data);
    }

    @Override    public int getCount() {
        return n.size();
    }

    @Override    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter,null);
        TextView tvname=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView tvlearningstyle=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvlearningstyle);
        tvname.setText(n.get(i));
        tvlearningstyle.setText(p.get(i));
        return view;
    }

}
```

Grouplist

```
package com.example.jcw3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.View;

public class GroupList extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView, listView2, listView3, listView4, listView5;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Button clear;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_list);

        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);

        db = openOrCreateDatabase("Mydata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        onViewData();
        onViewData2();
        onViewData3();

        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                deleteAll();
                openStudents();
            }
        });

    }

    public void onViewData() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            int groupsize = bundle.getInt("groupsize");
        }

        ArrayList<String> listname = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> listLearningstyle = new ArrayList<String>();
        listname.clear();
        listLearningstyle.clear();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select distinct NAME from id where LEARNINGSTYLE =Visual and LEARNINGSTYLE=VK order by NAME desc, LEARNINGSTYLE desc ", null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            listname.add(c.getString(1));
            listLearningstyle.add(c.getString(2));
        }
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.lv1);
        listView.setAdapter(new AdapterList(GroupList.this, listname, listLearningstyle) {
        });
    } //shows the 1st list view

    public void onViewData2() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            int groupsize = bundle.getInt("groupsize");
        }

        ArrayList<String> listname = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> listLearningstyle = new ArrayList<String>();
        listname.clear();
        listLearningstyle.clear();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select distinct NAME from id where LEARNINGSTYLE =Kinesthetic and LEARNINGSTYLE=VA order by NAME desc, LEARNINGSTYLE desc  ", null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            listname.add(c.getString(1));
            listLearningstyle.add(c.getString(2));
        }

        ListView listView2 = findViewById(R.id.lv2);
        listView2.setAdapter(new AdapterList(GroupList.this, listname, listLearningstyle) {
        });
    } //shows the 2nd list view

    public void onViewData3() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            int groupsize = bundle.getInt("groupsize");
        }

        ArrayList<String> listname = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> listLearningstyle = new ArrayList<String>();
        listname.clear();
        listLearningstyle.clear();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select distinct NAME from id where LEARNINGSTYLE =Aural and LEARNINGSTYLE=VAK order by NAME desc, LEARNINGSTYLE desc ", null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            listname.add(c.getString(1));
            listLearningstyle.add(c.getString(2));
        }
        ListView listView3 = findViewById(R.id.lv3);
        listView3.setAdapter(new AdapterList(GroupList.this, listname, listLearningstyle) {
        });
    } //shows the 3rd list view




    public void deleteAll() {
        db.delete("id", null, null); //delete all rows in a table
    }

    public void openStudents() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Students.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

2nd Adapterlist

```
package com.example.jcw3;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdapterList2 extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> n,p;
    GroupList2 l;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public AdapterList2(GroupList2 data,ArrayList<String> name,ArrayList<String> learningstyle){
        this.l=data;
        this.n=name;
        this.p=learningstyle;
        this.inflater=LayoutInflater.from(data);
    }

    @Override    public int getCount() {
        return n.size();
    }

    @Override    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter,null);
        TextView tvname=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView tvlearningstyle=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvlearningstyle);
        tvname.setText(n.get(i));
        tvlearningstyle.setText(p.get(i));
        return view;
    }

}
```

2nd Grouplist

```
package com.example.jcw3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.View;

public class GroupList2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView, listView2, listView3, listView4, listView5;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Button clear;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_list);

        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);

        db = openOrCreateDatabase("Mydata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        onViewData();
        onViewData2();
        onViewData3();
        onViewData4();

        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                deleteAll();
                openStudents();
            }
        });

    }

    public void onViewData() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            int groupsize = bundle.getInt("groupsize");
        }

        ArrayList<String> listname = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> listLearningstyle = new ArrayList<String>();
        listname.clear();
        listLearningstyle.clear();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select distinct NAME from id where LEARNINGSTYLE =Visual and LEARNINGSTYLE=VA order by NAME desc, LEARNINGSTYLE desc ", null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            listname.add(c.getString(1));
            listLearningstyle.add(c.getString(2));
        }
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.lv1);
        listView.setAdapter(new AdapterList2(GroupList2.this, listname, listLearningstyle) {
        });
    } //shows the 1st list view

    public void onViewData2() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            int groupsize = bundle.getInt("groupsize");
        }

        ArrayList<String> listname = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> listLearningstyle = new ArrayList<String>();
        listname.clear();
        listLearningstyle.clear();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select distinct NAME from id where LEARNINGSTYLE =Kinesthetic and LEARNINGSTYLE=VK order by NAME desc, LEARNINGSTYLE desc  ", null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            listname.add(c.getString(1));
            listLearningstyle.add(c.getString(2));
        }

        ListView listView2 = findViewById(R.id.lv2);
        listView2.setAdapter(new AdapterList2(GroupList2.this, listname, listLearningstyle) {
        });
    } //shows the 2nd list view

    public void onViewData3() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            int groupsize = bundle.getInt("groupsize");
        }

        ArrayList<String> listname = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> listLearningstyle = new ArrayList<String>();
        listname.clear();
        listLearningstyle.clear();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select distinct NAME from id where LEARNINGSTYLE =Aural and LEARNINGSTYLE=VA order by NAME desc, LEARNINGSTYLE desc ", null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            listname.add(c.getString(1));
            listLearningstyle.add(c.getString(2));
        }
        ListView listView3 = findViewById(R.id.lv3);
        listView3.setAdapter(new AdapterList2(GroupList2.this, listname, listLearningstyle) {
        });
    } //shows the 3rd list view

    public void onViewData4() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            int groupsize = bundle.getInt("groupsize");
        }

        ArrayList<String> listname = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> listLearningstyle = new ArrayList<String>();
        listname.clear();
        listLearningstyle.clear();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select distinct NAME from id where LEARNINGSTYLE =VA and LEARNINGSTYLE=VK order by NAME desc, LEARNINGSTYLE desc ", null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            listname.add(c.getString(1));
            listLearningstyle.add(c.getString(2));
        }
        ListView listView4 = findViewById(R.id.lv4);
        listView4.setAdapter(new AdapterList2(GroupList2.this, listname, listLearningstyle) {
        });
    } //shows the 4th list view




    public void deleteAll() {
        db.delete("id", null, null); //delete all rows in a table
    }

    public void openStudents() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Students.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

I expect it to run the query and then populate into the correct listview,
what happens however is the activity that should display the results is just blank.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following change in your adapter class:

```
@Override public Object getItem(int i) {
        return n.get(i);
    }

    @Override    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter,viewGroup,false);
        TextView tvname=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView tvlearningstyle=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvlearningstyle);
        tvname.setText(n.get(i));
        tvlearningstyle.setText(p.get(i));
        return view;
    }
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same result, Nothing displayed in the listview.
Could it be, because i'm using multiple adapters to pull from one table?